# open a folder in windows Explorer from html

Tags: windows, javascript, html5

I write a personal web app to sort my book , film , file , ... . It is just for my use and will not run on server , I wants to write some code in it that for example if I open a book in browser I can open its folder in windows too . but I can not do that it just open folder in browser , how I can open a folder in windows from my html?

Comment: Not possible in Chrome due to security. Internet Explorer can be used or Chrome extension. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446357/html-file-links-open-in-explorer-from-chrome

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible from HTML using `file://` protocol, example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="file://D:/">Open</a>
    </body>
</html>
```